# Does the Play! Framework have a built in (basic) web management console?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Some web frameworks have some built in features for tracking request stats, usage etc (some java app servers have a JMX console - for example). Is there anything like this baked into Play! 2 framework? (either via a URL or otherwise?)

Answer (score 1):

In Play 1.x, you can do the following.

When running your application using `play start` rather than `play run` you can then use `play status` to get a whole host of stats about your application.

there is also a module called `infoplay` but I don't think this has been maintained for a while, so I am not sure how much data this gives you. It may be worth a look though.

I am not aware of a module that currently exists in Play 2.0 at present, but I would expect that one will appear shortly.

Comment: is there an equivalent of this for when you are running things from a "dist" version of the app? (e.g. a production setting?)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work (play 2) - play start is blocking. Play status is not a valid command.

Comment: Apologies, I read the tag (playframework) and didnt realise you meant Play2.0. I have updated the tags to be more specific. The play start and play status are Play 1.x commands.

Comment: ah - yeah doesn't appear to exist yet for play2.